# Modeling an either/or relationship

Tags: database-design, relations

I've seen this post ([How should I model an “either/or” relationship?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19034/how-should-i-model-an-either-or-relationship)) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. both answers are suggesting creating a subtype instead of a relationship.

Say I have an entity `MACHINE`, and I want to creat a relationship to connect it with another entity `OS`, call it "installs" or whatsoever. And this `OS` has 2 subtypes: `WINDOWS` and `MAC` *(Linux and Unix also work but just for demo purpose they are not included)*. Not considering virtual machine or double OS, I can only choose one of these 2 subtypes of OS, how should I model this in the entity-relationship model?

[image: demo img]

Should I

- Create 1 relationship between `MACHINE` and `OS`. Or
- Create 2 relationship between `MACHINE` and `WINDOWS`, `MACHINE` and `MAC`. Or
- Create 1 ternary relationship between `MACHINE`, `WINDOWS` and `MAC`.

And should I add additional attributes to the entities or the relationship?

Thanks:D

Comment: Do you want to say that `WINDOWS` and `MAC` are considered as separate and independent entities which are stored in separate tables?

Comment: @Akina I'm still learning DB so I'm not sure what that means. From what I know, I guess they are separated. Say a Dell Alienware installs a Win10 Home, Alienware would be an instance of the entity `MACHINE`, win10 home would be an instance of entity `WINDOWS`, and they have a relationship. But having that relationship also means this Dell machine cannot install Mac.

Comment: I see 2 entities - MACHINE and OS. So - 2 tables. First - OS table which is self-referenced and stores everything as aa tree (parent-child), i.e. Windows and Mac are root instances, Windows 10 is an instance which have parent = Windows, Windows 10 Home is an instance which have parent = Windows 10, and so on... Second - MACHINE table which references to an instance in OS table, for example John's workstation is an instance which references to an instance Windows 10 Home in OS table.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually have subtypes or are missing an entity to enumerate which operating systems are offered by each manufacturer (and possible versions of each operating system)?

Comment: @bbaird I don't think manufacturer matters, think about choosing an OS to install on a computer, 2 OSs are available, but only 1 can be selected. Both OSs (`WINDOWS` and `MAC` in this case) are subclasses of the entity `OS`, and a relationship is needed to illustrate which OS is selected.

Comment: It may appear that way, but you're not going to have AppleOS on anything other than a Mac.  But I think you've answered your own question - if only one OS can be selected, there's not a subtype, just two or more choices for OS.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful design tool is still *natural language, predicates, and constraints*. So, when in doubt use a plain text editor. Simply focus on logic, as opposed to jargon (this-that relationship ..). The following is one possible version of this story:

```
-- Machine type TYP exists.
--
mtyp {TYP}
  PK {TYP}


-- data sample
  (TYP)
-------------------
  ('dell alienware')
, ('macbook pro')
, ('thinkpad')
, ('hp spectre')
```

```
-- Operating system OS exists.
--
osys {OS}
  PK {OS}


-- data sample
  (OS)
-------------
  ('windows')
, ('mac os')
, ('linux')
, ('unix')
```

```
-- Operating system OS is available for machine type TYP.
--
mtyp_osys {TYP, OS}
       PK {TYP, OS}

FK1 {TYP} REFERENCES mtyp {TYP}
FK2 {OS}  REFERENCES osys {OS}


-- data sample
  (TYP, OS)
-------------------------------
  ('dell alienware', 'windows')
, ('macbook pro'   , 'mac os')
, ('thinkpad'      , 'linux')
, ('thinkpad'      , 'windows')
, ('hp spectre'    , 'windows')
```

```
-- Machine number MCH# is of machine type TYP.
--
machine {MCH#, TYP}
     PK {MCH#}
     SK {MCH#, TYP}

FK1 {TYP} REFERENCES mtyp {TYP}


-- data sample
  (MCH#, TYP)
-------------------------------
  (1, 'dell alienware')
, (2, 'dell alienware')
, (3, 'dell alienware')
, (4, 'macbook pro')
, (5, 'thinkpad')
, (6, 'thinkpad')
, (7, 'hp spectre')
```

```
-- Operating system OS is installed
-- on machine number MCH#, machine type TYP.
--
install {MCH#, TYP, OS}
     PK {MCH#, TYP}

FK1 {MCH#, TYP} REFERENCES machine   {MCH#, TYP}
FK2 {TYP, OS}   REFERENCES mtyp_osys {TYP, OS}


-- data sample
  (MCH#, TYP)
-------------------------------
  (1, 'dell alienware', 'windows')
, (2, 'dell alienware', 'windows')
, (3, 'dell alienware', 'windows')
, (4, 'macbook pro'   , 'mac os')
, (5, 'thinkpad'      , 'windows')
, (6, 'thinkpad'      , 'linux')

-- at this point nothing is yet installed on machine # 7
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename MCH# to MCH_NO.
```

Here is another [example of design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262601/need-help-with-bcnf-decomposition-problem/262793#262793) using natural language, predicates, and constraints to keep a DB in high `NF`.